# Fourier transform with different measure

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

I am interested in the following question: can we generalize Fourier theory to different $L^2(\mu)$ spaces, not just the Lebesgue measure?
For example on $\mathbb{R}$, defining the Fourier transform of $f$ as
$$ \mathcal{F}[f](\omega)=\int_\mathbb{R}f(x)e^{-i\omega x}d\mu(x). $$

Is there literature on this subject? Do any properties hold with this (in particular Plancherel’s theorem)?  I have tried to look this idea up online but found nothing.

I am a beginner when it comes to Fourier theory, I apologize if it is a simple question.

Comment: This is the Fourier transform of $fd\mu$ which is a complex measure in general; these are part of Fourier theory (one can do Fourier transforms of even more general objects like distributions etc)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, in fact one can define it on measures on topological groups (besides integrable functions with respect to [Haar measures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pontryagin_duality)). In any event, lets just focus on $\mathbb{R}^n$. There, the Fourier transform is well define on the space of complex (or finite real valued) Borel measures $\mathcal{M}(\mathbb{R}^n)$. There is also an inversion formula that shows that the Fourier transform a one to one function on $\mathcal{M}$. The Fourier transform in this setting  is often used in probability theory under the name of characteristic function.

**Definition:**
Let $\mu$ be a Complex measure on
$(\mathbb{R}^d,\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R}^d))$. The **Fourier transform**  or **characteristic function**  of $\mu$ is the function defined as
$$\widehat{\mu}({\bf t})=\int\exp(i{\bf t}\cdot{\bf x})\mu(d{\bf x})$$

---

When $\mu\ll\lambda_d$ and $\mu=f\cdot\lambda_d$, then the Fourier transform of $\mu$ is closely related to the Fourier transform of $f$. and $\hat{\mu}(-2\pi i t)=\hat{f}(t)$.

---

Here are a few important results on uniqueness:

**Theorem:** Suppose that   $\mu$ and $\nu$ are complex measures (measures of finite variation) on $\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R}^d)$. Then, $\mu=\nu$ iff
$\widehat{\mu}=\widehat{\nu}$.

**Theorem:** Let $\mu$ be a complex Borel measure on $\mathbb{R}$ and let
$\widehat{\mu}$ be its characteristic function. Then

1. For any $-\infty<a<b <\infty$,
   $$
   \begin{align}
   \mu((a,b))+\frac12\mu(\{a,b\})=\frac{1}{2\pi}
   \lim_{T\rightarrow\infty}\int^T_{-T}\int^b_a
   e^{-iyt}\widehat{\mu}(t)\,dy\,dt \tag{1}\label{inversion}
   \end{align}
   $$

$$
\mu(\{a\})=\lim_{T\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{2T}\int^T_{-T}
e^{-iat}\widehat{\mu}(t)\,\tag{2}\label{two}
$$
2. If $f\in\mathcal{L}_1(\mathbb{R},\lambda)$ then
$$\begin{align}
f(x)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\lim_{T\rightarrow\infty}\int^T_{-T}e^{-iyt}\widehat{f}(-t/2\pi)\,dt\tag{3}\label{inversion3}
\qquad\text{a.s.}
\end{align}
$$
3. If $\widehat{\mu}\in\mathcal{L}_1$, then $\mu\ll\lambda$ and
$$\begin{align}
\frac{d\mu}{d\lambda}(y)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int
e^{-ity}\widehat{\mu}(t)\,dt\qquad\text{a.s.}\tag{4}\label{density-prob}
\end{align}
$$

With regards smoothness:

**Theorem:** Let $\mu$ be a finite positive measure on $(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R}^n))$. If $\partial^\alpha\widehat{\mu}(0)$ exits and is finite for all $|\alpha|=2m$ then,  $\widehat{\mu}\in\mathcal{C}^{2m}(\mathbb{R}^n)$; furthermore, for all  $\alpha\in\mathbb{Z}^n_+$ with $|\alpha|=2m$,
$\int |x^\alpha|\,\mu(dx)<\infty$ and $\partial^\alpha\widehat{\mu}(t)=i^{|\alpha|}\int x^\alpha e^{ix\cdot t}\,\mu(dx)$.

**Theorem:** Suppose that $\mu$ is a complex measure on $(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R}^n)$. If
$$
  \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}|x_j|^m|\mu|(dx)<\infty,
  $$
then the partial derivative
$\partial^m_j\widehat{\mu}$ exists,  is uniformly continuous, and
$$\begin{align}
\partial^k_j \widehat{\mu}(t)=i^k\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} x^k_j e^{i x\cdot t}\mu(dx),\quad 0\leq k\leq m.
\end{align}\tag{1}\label{deriv-m-charac}
$$
Moreover, if $|x|^m=\Big(\sum^n_{j=1}x^2_j\Big)^{\frac{m}{2}}\in\mathcal{L}_1(|\mu|)$, then $\widehat{\mu}\in\mathcal{C}^m(\mathbb{R}^n)$, and
$$\begin{align}
\widehat{\mu}(t)= \sum_{0\leq|\alpha|\leq m}\frac{i^{|\alpha|}}{\alpha!}t^\alpha \int x^\alpha\,\mu(dx) + o(|t|^m)\tag{2}\label{otaylor}
\end{align}$$

**Theorem:** (Bochner--Herglotz)
$\varphi:\mathbb{R}^d\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ is the characteristic
function of a finite nonnegative measure $\mu$ in  $\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R}^d)$
iff $\varphi$ is a bounded positive definite  continuous function.

Comment: Great answer, thank you!! One more question, do you know if there exists any Plancherel-like theorems for Fourier transforms of measures?

Comment: Consider the measure $\delta_0$ that assigns mass one to the point $x=0$ and no mass to sets that do not contained $0$, that is $\delta_0(A)=\mathbb{1}_A(0)$, then for any Borel measurable $f$ one has rear $$\int f(x)\,\delta_0(dx) = f(0)$$ in particular, for $f(x)=e^{i xt} $ one gets $\widehat{\delta_0}(t)\equiv1$ so the Fourier transform of a measure may not be in $C_0$. Of course, if your measure has density, you are back to the situation of Fourier transforms of functions (integrable) where the Fourier transform vanishes at infinity

Comment: plancherel’s theorem is particular to L2.. for measures, as for functions in $L_1$ you have $\|\widehat{\mu}\|_u\leq\|\mu\|_{TV}$ where $\|\,\|_{TV}$ is the total variation of $\mu$

Comment: Fourier transform of a measure $\mu$ and Fourier transform with respect to a measure $\mu$ (in place of Lebesgue measure) are two different things. Although there is a connection.

Comment: @Oliver Diaz Is there a reasonably standard published reference for these results, especially the first two? Thank you. Great answer.

Comment: @Oliver Diaz These results for probability measures are well known. I was looking for rigorous published treatment of finite complex Borel measures. I guess the search goes on...

Comment: @encore: the inversion formula for finite variation methods can be obtained just as in the proof you see in probability books (substitution a probability measure $\mu$ by a finite variation measure goes through). Like I said, the fact that $\{\gamma_t(x)=e^{itx}:t\in\mathbb{R}\}$ is a multiplicative family that generated the Borel $\sigma$-algebra yields uniqueness of the Fourier transform. Modifications results about of moments and derivatives from probability setting to finite variation measures is easy (dominates convergence  and induction, just as for probability measures).

Comment: @encore: That $\{\gamma_t:t\in\mathbb{R}\}$ as in my comment generated the Borel $\sigma$-algebra is the complex bounded class theorem ( a companion of monotone class theorem) See Bichteler's Stochastic Integration with Jumps, Theorem A.3.4 and exercise A.3.5. Bochner's theorem appears in many textbooks on functional analysis and harmonic analysis (Folland's book on abstract harmonic analysis has a derivation of it for general Haar measures)

Comment: I think you misstate this: $\hat{\mu}(-2\pi i)=\hat{f}(t)$.  Perhaps the left side should have $t$ in it.

Comment: @Oliver Diaz I get it now. Thank you! The Bichteler reference helps.